# Div opacity not working

Tags: javascript

I have a timer on my div which changes the opacity of the div. But for some reason the maths keeps setting it to 0.1 over and over. And i have no idea why!

This is my code:

```
function do_it(div){
  var opac = parseInt(div.style.opacity);

 if(opac == 1){
   var dir = 'down';
 } else if(opac == 0) {
   var dir = 'up';
 }

 if(dir == 'down'){
    opac -= 0.1;
 } else {
    opac += 0.1;
 }

 if(opac > 1){
   opac = 1;
 } else if(opac < 0){
   opac = 0;
 }

div.style.opacity = opac;
div.timer = setTimeout(function(){ do_it(div) }, 1000);

}
```

Have provided a fiddle:

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ckBFy/4/)

The div opacity should go from 1 to 0 and back up again in steps of `0.1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your problem

```
var opac = parseInt(div.style.opacity);
```

It should be parseFloat

```
var opac = parseFloat(div.style.opacity);
```

Comment: @Dave - OT, but when using `parseInt`, remember to supply the radix. Otherwise JS will try to be intelligent when parsing, which you may not want. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_it(div,output){
  var opac = parseFloat(div.style.opacity);
  opac -= 0.1;
  if(opac<=0.05){
    opac = 1;
  }
  div.style.opacity = opac;
  output.innerHTML = opac;
  div.timer = setTimeout(function(){ do_it(div,output) }, 1000);
}

var div = document.getElementById('test');
var output = document.getElementById('op');
do_it(div,output);
```

1. parse a number

   - parseInt(0.9)   ==> 0
   - parseFloat(0.9) ==>0.9
2. there is no need of extra vars lik `up` `down`

http://jsfiddle.net/ckBFy/29/

Comment: You should see the OP's original intention reflected through his code: he didn't mean to "circle around" by jumping from zero to one and then go down again - he meant to go down from 1 to zero and then up from zero to one in jumps of -0.1/+0.1 respectively. He also expressed it on the last line of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there's already an accepted answer, I'd like to add that I think that it's still not working the way it was supposed to.

Here's a link to [*my demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/ckBFy/32/) (the way I believe it should have worked).
And here's my corrected version of the code:

```
way = 'down';
function do_it(div,output){

    var opac = parseFloat(div.style.opacity);

    if(opac >= 1){
        way = 'down';
    } 
    else if(opac <= 0.2) {
        way = 'up';
    }
    if (way === 'down'){
        opac -= 0.1;
    }
    else{
        opac += 0.1;
    }

    div.style.opacity = opac;
    output.innerHTML = opac;

    div.timer = setTimeout(function(){ do_it(div,output) }, 1000);
}

var div = document.getElementById('test');
var output = document.getElementById('op');
do_it(div,output);
```